# Resolve() method of Recipient class makes Outlook UI delayed?

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook, add-in

I created a project, which will get all information of all contacts in Outlook.
When I run my project with Outlook which has large contacts (about 5k items), Outlook UI will be delayed, and got "not responding" status.

I detected the problem is

```
rcp.Resolve();
```

(rcp is Recipient instance).
Then I commented this line, and everything is OK.

So, what this line use for? And Why does it make Outlook UI delayed?

Here is my code:

```
private static string GetEmailAddress(Outlook.NameSpace otl, string email, string emailtype, ref int nCount)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
        return email;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(emailtype))
        return email;
    if (String.Compare(emailtype, "SMTP", true) == 0)
        return email;
    string sEmailIn = email;
    Recipient rcp = null;
    try
    {
        rcp = otl.CreateRecipient(email);
        rcp.Resolve();
        if (rcp != null && rcp.Resolved)
        {
            AddressEntry address = rcp.AddressEntry;
            if (address != null)
            {
                ExchangeUser user = address.GetExchangeUser();
                if (user != null)
                {
                    email = user.PrimarySmtpAddress;
                    ++nCount;
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(user);
                }
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(address);                        
            }
        }                
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLn("Exception while converting email: " + sEmailIn);
        Console.WriteLn("Content " + ex);
        Console.WriteLn("Resulting email: " + email);
        return sEmailIn;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (rcp != null)
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rcp);
        }
    }
    return email;
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I opened Task Manager and found out this info.

- If I run the code above which inclued the rcp.Resolve() method, CPU of OUTLOOK.EXE process was 25-30%, and it maked Outlook app delayed
- Otherwise, if I run this code without the line rcp.Resolved() method, CPU of OUTLOOK.EXE process was 0-3%, and it did NOT make Outlook app delayed

Comment: You removed the Resolve() and everything is working for you? Is the code flow going inside the if? because the Resolve() method sets the Resolved property

Comment: Yes, if I removed the Resolve(), everything is working for me. Outlook runs normaly whithout delaying. In this step, I just want to get exchange email of a contact, so if I remove this line, there are any error? I misunderstand "the Resolve() method sets the Resolved property"? Could you explain for me. Thanks.

Comment: Lets leave the performance for a moment and concentrate on the correctness. When you do not call Resolve() the resolved property is not set which means your code should not enter the if block. You are in my opinion just returning the string that came in the function. What is `sEmailin`. What happens when you give a valid email address which does not exist? Lets correct the code and then go to performance.